# Universe-sized groups with only set-sized normal subgroups, their cardinality in a certain range

Tags: set-theory, forcing, lo.logic, gr.group-theory

Let $\kappa$ be an inaccessible cardinal, and let $G$ be a group with $|G| \geq \kappa$. For any cardinal $\lambda \le \kappa$ (regular, say, but not necessary), say $G$ is $\lambda$-simple if for all normal subgroups $N \lt G$ we have $|N| \lt \lambda$. Clearly a group is simple iff it is $2$-simple. Can we force (or even construct without forcing) a $\lambda$-simple group $G$?

---

EDIT: Yes, take a simple group of the required cardinality, this exists by Goldstern's comment. Note that $\lambda$-simple implies $\alpha$-simple for all $\alpha \gt \lambda$.

A more interesting question (pointed out by Benjamin Steinberg) is whether we can bound the size of the normal subgroups from below as well. Given a second cardinal $\lambda' \lt \lambda$, can we find a group of cardinality $\ge \kappa$ such that all normal $N \lt G$ have $\lambda' \lt |N| \lt \lambda$?

Comment: Do you mean $\le \lambda$ or $<\lambda$?    Anyway, it seems to me that every simple group is $\lambda$-simple, or have I misunderstood the question?   There are simple groups of any cardinality $\kappa$, e.g. the set of "even" permutations on a set of size $\kappa$. (The smallest normal subgroup containing all 3-cycles.)

Comment: Maybe he means $\lambda$-simple and not $\lambda'$-simple for $\lambda'<\lambda$. Some motivation would make this clearer.

Comment: Benjamin Steinberg's version of this question sounds interesting.

Comment: Whoops, I did mean |N| < lambda. You've answered my question Goldstern, thanks.

Comment: @Benjamin, I'm thinking of a pair of groups $L \lt G$ of cardinality $\geq \kappa$ such that $L$ contains no normal $N \lt G$ of cardinality $\kappa$. But if I can just take $G$ simple, then I am done.

Comment: Ok, maybe somebody will answer my wacky version. 

Comment: You posted the same question to FOM on Nov 20.  I think it makes sense to link to such crosspostings, to avoid duplication of work. 

See http://www.cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2011-November/015964.html 


Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few  answers with references:

The answer to the original question is "yes": There are simple groups of any infinite cardinality.  For example, the set of all permutations of $\kappa$ with finite support has normal subgroup $A_\kappa$ of index 2, the even permutations; $A_\kappa$ has cardinality $\kappa$ and is simple.

More examples of simple groups of any infinite cardinality can be found in Lang's book "Algebra", chapter XIII, sections 8 and 9.

For the special case of $\kappa = 2^{\aleph_0}$, $\lambda=\aleph_1$,
[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group#Normal_subgroups) mentions  Ch 11.3 in Scott's 1987 book on Group Theory and Ch. 8.1 in Dixon-Mortimer's 1996 book on permutation groups as references for the following theorem:

- The symmetric group on a countable set has only 2 nontrivial normal subgroups, both of them countable: even permutations, and permutations with finite support.